# How to create a new tag in a local repo using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I want to create a new lightweight tag in my local repo using LibGit2Sharp. I have no intent to push it to the remote (I'm using tags as short-term bookmarks); knowing how to also push to the remote would be handy, but I am most interested in just creating a tag in a local repo without pushing to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

As follows:

```
using LibGit2Sharp;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a lightweight tag in the specified local repo:
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tagName">Name to be given to the tag</param>
    /// <param name="repoFolder">Repo folder location (path)</param>
    /// <param name="commitSha">Hash identifying the commit to receive the tag</param>
    public static void CreateTag(string tagName, string repoFolder, string commitSha)
    {
        using (var repo = new Repository(repoFolder))
        {
            var commit = repo.Lookup<Commit>(commitSha);
            if (commit != null)
            {
                repo.ApplyTag(tagName, commitSha);
            }
        }
    }
```